# "org.json.JSONArray implements Serializable": What's the best option to achieve this?

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, grails

I am using Grails Webflow, what ever object I pass to a view, it must be Serialized.
My domain models "implement Serializable", so they work.

The problem is when I get a response from a WebService.
It is of the org.json.JSONArray class.

I just want to pass the whole Array over to the view yet it doesn't implement Serializable,
so it fails,

Any thoughts on how I can pass this, or my best option?

Can I just edit the source of the org.json library and make every class "imp Serializable"?

Or process the result into Domain objects that do "imp Serializable"

Comment: What does your view do with the `JSONArray`?

Comment: I want to print out values from this array,
So I could always process the array into a normal array of serializable objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap it as a `transient` property in a class which implements `Serializable` and has the `readObject()` and `writeObject()` overridden.

```
public class SerializableJSONArray implements Serializable {
    private transient JSONArray jsonArray;

    public SerializableJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    }

    public JSONArray getJSONArray() {
        return jsonArray;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
        oos.defaultWriteObject();
        oos.writeObject(jsonArray.toString());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, JSONException {
        ois.defaultReadObject();
        jsonArray = new JSONArray((String) ois.readObject());
    }
}
```

You see that there's a getter which returns the wrapped JSONArray. Use it in your domain objects instead. Optionally you can also let this class `extends JSONArray` and delegate all of its methods to the wrapped JSONArray. A decent IDE can autogenerate them for you in a second.

Comment: won't this cause the variable to be lost?

Comment: superb solution!

Answer (score 1):

Can't remember the behavior of that actual class but you could just pass it as `String` representation *(which obviously is `Serializable`)* of the JSON and then re-parse it to `JSONArray` on the other side - at least `JSONObject` can be constructed directly from JSON String and from the top of my head I can't think of why `JSONArray` wouldn't be too.

Comment: Mh, sadly the class just has to implement Serializable,
I can't parse it on the view side, its placed in the Session to be moved around, for compactness I'd say

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-io-notserializableexception-how-to-solve-not-serializable-exception/), all you need to do is to declare the JSONArray object as transient. Once it is declared as transient, it is ignored by the serializable runtime.